# Multiple VLANs per NIC Failing on IPv6

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, vlan

I run a dual-stack (IPv4 and IPv6) home network, with a few VLANs to segregate IoT devices (VLAN 20) from normal users (VLAN 10) from network hardware (untagged VLAN). I'm currently hosting local DNS (and a few other services) on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ (running raspbian), which normally lives on the untagged VLAN, but I'd like to try giving it addresses on the other 2 VLANs (10 and 20) as an experiment (simplify firewall rules, reduce router load, etc). My first attempt at this failed, so I tried to simplify things and just place it on the untagged VLAN plus VLAN 10, but that also failed, and I can't understand why.

## Single address setup

Here's the normal setup (only an address on the untagged VLAN, nothing on the VLAN 10 or 20):

`/etc/network/interfaces` is empty.

Here's `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
hostname
clientid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option ntp_servers
option interface_mtu
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.10/24
static ip6_address=fd:<STATIC_IPv6_ULA>/64
static routers=192.168.1.1 fd:<STATIC_IPv6_ULA_FOR_ROUTER>
static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1 ::1
```

And here are the resulting addresses I get:

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC_ADDR> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.10/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd:<IPv6_ULA_FROM_SLAAC>/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic
       valid_lft 85965sec preferred_lft 13965sec
    inet6 <IPv6_GLOBAL_ADDR_FROM_SLAAC>/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic
       valid_lft 85965sec preferred_lft 13965sec
    inet6 fd:<STATIC_IPv6_ULA>/64 scope global noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::<IPv6_LLA>/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This works fine, I can route to hosts on VLANs 10 and 20 through the router. The trouble comes when trying to add an interface on one of the VLANs...

## Adding a VLAN

To add an address on VLAN 10, I added the following configuration on top of the configuration in the single-address setup:

Here's `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0.10

iface eth0.10 inet manual
  vlan-raw-device eth0

iface eth0.10 inet6 manual
  vlan-raw-device eth0
```

Here's `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface eth0.10
static ip_address=10.0.10.10/24
static ip6_address=fd:<STATIC_IPv6_VLAN_10_ULA>/64
static routers=10.0.10.1 <STATIC_IPv6_VLAN_10_ULA_FOR_ROUTER>
static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1 ::1
```

And here are the resulting addresses I get:

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC_ADDR> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.10/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd:<STATIC_IPv6_ULA>/64 scope global noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth0.10@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC_ADDR> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.10.10/24 brd 10.0.10.255 scope global eth0.10
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd:<IPv6_VLAN_10_ULA_FROM_SLAAC>/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic
       valid_lft 86377sec preferred_lft 14377sec
    inet6 <IPv6_GLOBAL_ADDR_FROM_SLAAC>/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic
       valid_lft 86377sec preferred_lft 14377sec
    inet6 fd:<STATIC_IPv6_VLAN_10_ULA>/64 scope global noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::<IPv6_LLA>/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This was very strange, I lost my global IPv6 address on the untagged VLAN, as well as my link-local address (LLA) and the ULA I get from SLAAC. I tried out some pings to see what worked, and here's what I found:

```
$ ping -4 -I eth0 www.google.com
<SUCCESS>
$ ping -4 -I eth0.10 www.google.com
<SUCCESS>
$ ping -6 -I eth0 www.google.com
connect: Network is unreachable
$ ping -6 -I eth0.10 www.google.com
<SUCCESS>
```

So, IPv4 was working fine on both VLANs, but IPv6 was broken on the untagged VLAN. I looked at `syslog` for all messages related to `dhcpcd`, and found these:

```
00:28:23 HOSTNAME systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
00:28:23 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: dev: loaded udev
00:28:23 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0: waiting for carrier
00:28:23 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0.10: waiting for carrier
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0: carrier acquired
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: DUID <DUID>
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0: IAID <IAID>
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0: IAID conflicts with one assigned to eth0.10
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0: adding address fe80::<IPv6_LLA>
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0: adding address fd:<STATIC_IPv6_ULA>/64
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0: adding route to fd:<STATIC_IPv6_ULA_PREFIX>/64
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0: probing address 192.168.1.10/24
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0.10: carrier acquired
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0.10: IAID <IAID>
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0.10: IAID conflicts with one assigned to eth0
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0: deleting address fe80::<IPv6_LLA>
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0.10: adding address fe80::<IPv6_LLA>
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0.10: adding address fd:<STATIC_IPv6_VLAN_10_ULA>/64
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0.10: adding route to fd:<STATIC_IPv6_ULA_VLAN_10_PREFIX>/64
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0.10: probing address 10.0.10.10/24
00:28:24 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
00:28:25 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0.10: soliciting an IPv6 router
00:28:29 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0.10: using static address 10.0.10.10/24
00:28:29 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0.10: adding route to 10.0.10.0/24
00:28:29 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: eth0.10: adding default route via 10.0.10.1
00:28:29 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[340]: forked to background, child pid 603
00:28:29 HOSTNAME systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
00:28:30 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[603]: eth0: using static address 192.168.1.10/24
00:28:30 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[603]: eth0: adding route to 192.168.1.0/24
00:28:30 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[603]: eth0: adding default route via 192.168.1.1
00:28:30 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[603]: eth0.10: Router Advertisement from fe80::<IPv6_LLA_OF_ROUTER>
00:28:30 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[603]: eth0.10: adding address <IPv6_GLOBAL_ADDR_FROM_SLAAC>/64
00:28:30 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[603]: eth0.10: adding address <IPv6_VLAN_10_ULA_FROM_SLAAC>/64
00:28:30 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[603]: eth0.10: adding route to <IPv6_GLOBAL_PREFIX_FROM_SLAAC>/64
00:28:30 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[603]: eth0.10: adding default route via fe80::<IPv6_LLA_OF_ROUTER>
00:29:17 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[603]: eth0.10: fe80::<IPv6_LLA_OF_ROUTER> is unreachable, expiring it
00:30:08 HOSTNAME dhcpcd[603]: eth0.10: fe80::<IPv6_LLA_OF_ROUTER> is reachable again
```

So, it seems there's an issue that results in the LLA getting deleted on the untagged VLAN, which prevents it from seeing router advertisements on that interface.

I'm guessing that this setup should be possible (multiple VLANs per NIC working with IPv6). Any ideas on what is causing this problem? Is this just a configuration goof by me?

In case it's useful, here's the kernel version of raspbian running on the Raspberry Pi:

```
$ uname -a
Linux HOSTNAME 4.14.70-v7+ #1144 SMP Tue Sep 18 17:34:46 BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Quick shot: The MAC addresses (which you edited out) of the untagged and the tagged interface is the same, so the ff80:... link-local IPv6 addresses are the same, so one gets deleted.

Comment: @dirkt: They are allowed to be the same, _because_ they are link-local and are therefore in different scopes. If dhcpcd is deleting them as duplicate, that's bogus.

Comment: @pewter-bronco: What dhcpcd version are you using? Support for automatic IAIDs of VLAN tagged interfaces was only added in release 7.0.0.

Comment: Good point @grawity, looks like the default raspbian version of dhcpcd is 3.2.3-11. Slightly out of date =P I'll look into updating that...

Comment: Ya, dhcpcd is way out of date in debian: https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/dhcpcd

Comment: Well, it looks like the `apt` version number of `dhcpcd` doesn't agree with the one that's actually on the system:
`$ sudo dhcpcd --version`
`dhcpcd 6.11.5`
`Copyright (c) 2006-2016 Roy Marples`
`Compiled in features: INET IPv4LL INET6 DHCPv6 AUTH`
Still needs to be updated though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip @grawity! The problem was simply that `dhcpcd` was out of date.  As @grawity mentioned in the comments above, `dhcpcd` only added support for automatic IAIDs on VLAN tagged interfaces in version 7.0.0. Here was the version on my raspbian system using the default installation from `apt`:

```
$ sudo dhcpcd --version
dhcpcd 6.11.5
Copyright (c) 2006-2016 Roy Marples
Compiled in features: INET IPv4LL INET6 DHCPv6 AUTH
```

In case it helps anyone, here are the steps I took to install the latest version (7.0.8) from source:

Check https://github.com/rsmarples/dhcpcd/releases for the latest version of `dhcpcd`.

```
wget https://github.com/rsmarples/dhcpcd/archive/dhcpcd-7.0.8.tar.gz
tar xzf dhcpcd-7.0.8.tar.gz
cd dhcpcd-dhcpcd-7.0.8
./configure --libexecdir=/lib/dhcpcd --dbdir=/var/lib/dhcpcd5
make
sudo make install
```

Note that I set `dbdir` to `/var/lib/dhcpcd5`, even though [these instructions](https://github.com/rsmarples/dhcpcd/blob/master/BUILDING.md#default-directories) generally recommend using `/var/lib/dhcpcd`. On my system, `/var/lib/dhcpcd5` was already being used by the existing installation of `dhcpcd`, and `/var/lib/dhcpcd` didn't exist. Do whatever makes sense for you.

Now that that's done:

```
$ sudo dhcpcd --version
dhcpcd 7.0.8
Copyright (c) 2006-2018 Roy Marples
Compiled in features: INET ARP ARPing IPv4LL INET6 DHCPv6 AUTH
```

And now everything works perfectly with the added VLAN 10 interface (and it also works when I add in the VLAN 20 interface). Here's what things look like with just the VLAN 10 interface added:

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC_ADDR> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.10/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd:<IPv6_ULA_FROM_SLAAC>/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic
       valid_lft 86382sec preferred_lft 14382sec
    inet6 <IPv6_GLOBAL_ADDR_FROM_SLAAC>/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic
       valid_lft 86382sec preferred_lft 14382sec
    inet6 fd:<STATIC_IPv6_ULA>/64 scope global noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::<IPv6_LLA>/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth0.10@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC_ADDR> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.10.10/24 brd 10.0.10.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0.10
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd:<IPv6_VLAN_10_ULA_FROM_SLAAC>/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic
       valid_lft 86381sec preferred_lft 14381sec
    inet6 <IPv6_VLAN_10_GLOBAL_ADDR_FROM_SLAAC>/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic
       valid_lft 86381sec preferred_lft 14381sec
    inet6 fd:<STATIC_IPv6_VLAN_10_ULA>/64 scope global noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::<IPv6_LLA_2>/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Interestingly, the LLA for each interface is unique. It looks like it's being derived from the IAID, which I can see from `syslog` is unique on each interface now. For eth0, my IAID is derived from my MAC address, but for the VLAN 10 interface, the IAID is simply `ff:00:00:0a`. For the VLAN 20 interface, it is `ff:00:00:14`. So, it would appear that the IAID is just `ff::VLAN_NUMBER`, which leads to unique LLAs on each interface. Whatever, that's more of a curiosity than a real issue...

Regardless, all of the interfaces get configured properly, and they can all reach internal network hosts as well as external internet hosts. Thanks again @grawity!

Comment: Note for other users of raspbian encountering this issue: Raspbian Buster comes packaged with an up to date version of dhcpcd. Upgrading to Buster should also fix this.